# How to convert String to Json Object in java or groovy

Tags: java, data-structures, groovy

I saved a json into the database as a string like this:

`"[_district:_1_2_5village, _name:_1_1_2id_inter, _gender:_1_3_5sex]"`

Now i want to convert it back to a Json Object so as to pick the key and value eg **_district** is the key and **_1_2_5village** is the value. Any help on how i can achieve this. Thanks

I tried to convert the string back into JSON by parsing but that dint work for me.

Comment: json should look like this: `{ "_district": "_1_2_5village", "_name": "_1_1_2id_inter", "_gender": "_1_3_5sex" }`

Comment: If you're saving invalid text into the database, you probably want to start with fixing that, instead of writing a custom parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because that's not a JSON format, a JSON is a way of mapping objects and uses key value syntax like so:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

and an array would look like this:

```
[{"key": "value"},{"key": "value"}]
```

You'll need to make a custom parser for your syntax

Here's the json specification:

https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, Teddy. I fixed the format to save a JSON.